# Missing EditingSession and FilterFactory in Nokia Imaging SDK v1.2.115.0 HDR example

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, blending, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am trying to use [this code](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HDR_I_-_Implementing_High_Dynamic_Range_filters_using_Nokia_Imaging_SDK) in my project but it appears that `EditingSession` and `FilterFactory` classes are no longer supported in SDK v1.2.115.0

Original code

```
WriteableBitmap toneMap1 = new WriteableBitmap(CapturedImage.PixelWidth, CapturedImage.PixelHeight);

using (EditingSession editsession = new EditingSession(image1.AsBitmap()))
using (EditingSession blendSession = new EditingSession(image1.AsBitmap()))
{
// Create the blurred version of original image
editsession.AddFilter(FilterFactory.CreateBlurFilter(BlurLevel.Blur1));

// Perform the difference between the original image and the blurred copy
editsession.AddFilter(FilterFactory.CreateBlendFilter(blendSession, BlendFunction.Difference));               

// Create the Laplacian of the original image using the emboss filter
blendSession.AddFilter(FilterFactory.CreateEmbossFilter(1.0f));

// Add the result of blur with emboss filter
editsession.AddFilter(FilterFactory.CreateBlendFilter(blendSession, BlendFunction.Add));

// Perform a gray scale as we need just informations on radiance not colours
editsession.AddFilter(FilterFactory.CreateGrayscaleFilter());

// Render the result
await editsession.RenderToWriteableBitmapAsync(toneMap1, OutputOption.PreserveAspectRatio);
}
```

This is what I've attempted so far

```
        IList<IFilter> filtersList = new List<IFilter>();

        var blurFilter = new BlurFilter()
        { 
            BlurRegionShape = BlurRegionShape.Rectangular,
            KernelSize = 10
        };


        var blendFilter = new BlendFilter()
        {
            BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Difference,                
        };

        var embossFilter = new EmbossFilter()
        {
            Level = 1.0f
        };

        var blendFilter2 = new BlendFilter()
        {
            BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add
        };

        var grayScaleFilter = new GrayscaleFilter();

        filtersList.Add(blurFilter);
        filtersList.Add(blendFilter);
        filtersList.Add(embossFilter);
        filtersList.Add(blendFilter2);
        filtersList.Add(grayScaleFilter);


            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image1.SaveJpeg(ms, image1.PixelWidth, image1.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var streamImageSource1 = new StreamImageSource(ms))
                using (var filterEffect1 = new FilterEffect(streamImageSource1) { Filters = filtersList })
                using (var writableBitmapRenderer1 = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(filterEffect1, toneMap1))
                {
                    toneMap1 = await writableBitmapRenderer1.RenderAsync();
                }
            }
```

Error is raised because the `ForegroundSource` of the BlendFilter is empty. The `ForegroundSource` should be the result of the previous filters (in this case blurFilter and embossFilter), no?

But since I can't use `EditingSession` and `FilterFactory`, how do I properly change the code to work with the updated SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. For those who are in the same boat, here's what I did

```
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image2.SaveJpeg(ms, image2.PixelWidth, image2.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var oriStreamImageSource2 = new StreamImageSource(ms))
                {
                    //Create the blurred version of original image
                    var blurEffect = new FilterEffect(oriStreamImageSource2)
                    {
                        Filters = new[] { new BlurFilter() { KernelSize = BlurLevel } }
                    };

                    var blendEffect1 = new FilterEffect(blurEffect)
                    {
                        Filters = new[] { new BlendFilter(oriStreamImageSource2, BlendFunction.Difference) }
                    };

                    //Create the Laplacian of the original image using the emboss filter
                    var embossEffect = new FilterEffect(oriStreamImageSource2)
                    {
                        Filters = new[] { new EmbossFilter(1.0f) }
                    };

                    //Add the result of blur with emboss filter
                    var blendEffect2 = new FilterEffect(blendEffect1)
                    {
                        Filters = new[] { new BlendFilter(embossEffect, BlendFunction.Add) }
                    };

                    //Perform a gray scale as we need just informations on radiance not colours
                    var grayScaleEffect = new FilterEffect(blendEffect2)
                    {
                        Filters = new[] { new GrayscaleFilter() }
                    };

                    using (var writableBitmapRenderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(grayScaleEffect, toneMap2))
                    {
                        toneMap2 = await writableBitmapRenderer.RenderAsync();

                        blurEffect.Dispose();
                        blendEffect1.Dispose();
                        embossEffect.Dispose();
                        blendEffect2.Dispose();
                        grayScaleEffect.Dispose();
                    }
                };
            }
```